# Listing content from two directories with wildcard

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

I have a task to list all files from `/bin` and `/usr/bin` that contain an `e` that is neither at the beginning nor at the end.
The wildcard is `[!e]*e*[!e]` and works.
(Tested commands `cd /bin & ls -l [!e]*e*[!e]`

The problem is I have to print the contents of **both directories** using this wildcard in *one* command. How do I do that?

Comment: try ... `ls /bin/?*e*? /usr/bin/?*e*?`

Comment: Oh sure your version works I forgot that the wildcard specifies a relative path. Thank you!

Comment: `/bin/egrep` contains a `e` that is neither at the beginning nor end, should it be matched? Your wildcard doesn't match it.

Comment: I might be pendantic and ask if "an" e means exactly one e or allows for more than one?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No. The filename must not begin with an `e`

Comment: @JeffSchaller The filename should contain an `e` that is neither at the beginning nor at the end. It should count one or more `e`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could boil it down to one command *and* one (typed) argument:

```
ls -d {/usr,}/bin/[^e]*e*[^e]
```

I added `-d` in case there to be subdirectories matching the pattern. That expands in phases to:

1. `/usr/bin/[^e]*e*[^e]` and
2. `/bin/[^e]*e*[^e]`

after expanding the braces.

The `[^e]` requires something other than an `e`, followed by `*` anything, followed by an `e`, followed by `*` anything, followed by another non-`e` (followed implicitly by nothing -- indicating the end of the filename).

Comment: Looks very interesting but it says: ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/[!e]*e*[!e]': No such file or directory & ls: cannot access '/bin/[!e]*e*[!e]': No such file or directory

Comment: I see you have `!` instead of `^` as I used; are you using bash?

Comment: `!` is correct in globbing patterns. The pattern would remain unexpanded if it doesn't match anything.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I did try ^ instead of ! but it keeps print the same error. And yes, I use the bash.

Comment: It would seem to me that you simply don't have any of those files, then. Does that seem right?